# Ignore files on TFS merge

Tags: tfs, merge

I recently moved from a svn shop to one that uses TFS. One of the issues I'm having in using the TFS merge is ignoring files. Our branches have several files that we never want to merge(version info, ivy files etc) and we have to manually uncheck them each time we run a merge. I know in SVN there is a file property you can set to ignore files during a merge, does TFS have anything similar?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are those files in source control to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

From the command line, you can use something like the following:

```
tf.exe merge /discard <path to the file to exclude>
```

That will update the merge history as if the file had been already merged, so it won't continue appearing in the merge candidates list.